# How would I close this space up on the right? Using Shopify liquid

Tags: html, shopify, themes, liquid, customizer

I am by no means a web developer in any way, but I am teaching myself very basic HTML through my job. I just edit the front end of the website on Shopify using the online theme customizer, but sometimes it requires some hard coding and we don't have a web dev at the moment.

There used to be 3 dates here, but they want one removed, and then re-centered with just the two. Is this possible? If so, how?
[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAQHu.png)

I tried making the font size bigger but it didn't do anything in terms of spacing/alignment because i have no idea what i'm doing lol.

Comment: Hi, interestingly named person.  We need to see your HTML and not a screen shot.  Please check [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information on how to ask a question.  Good luck!